# Expand environment variable inside Perl regex

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I am having trouble with a short bash script. It seems like all forward slashes needs to be escaped. How can required characters in expanded (environment) variables be escaped before perl reads them? Or some other method that perl understands.

This is what I am trying to do, but this will not work properly.

```
eval "perl -pi -e 's/$HOME\/_TV_rips\///g'" '*$videoID.info.json'
```

That is part of a longer script where `videoID=$1`. (And for some reason perl expands variables both within single and double quotes.)

This simple workaround with no forward slash in the expanded environment variable `$USER` works. But I would like to not have `/Users/` hard coded:

```
eval "perl -pi -e 's/\/Users\/$USER\/_TV_rips\///g'" '*$videoID.info.json'
```

This is probably solvable in some better way fetching home dir for files or something else. The goal is to remove the folder name in youtube-dl's json data.
I am using perl just because it can handle extended regex. But perl is not required. Any better substitute for extended regex on macOS is welcome.

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Comment: Not really. I am describing my current method that I am having problem with and also describe my overall goal in the last paragraph. And also stating that I am open to other methods as well, but also curious what goes wrong with perl and to solve that - even if there is another better solution that I might be inspired by the in answers.

Comment: If I get it right you want to change the string $HOME with _TV_rips in your first example.

Comment: I don't get it why you would use eval here

Comment: You can use `s{...}{...}` instead of `s/.../.../`  to avoid escaping `/` (since it is no longer the separator in the statement. You could also use `$ENV{HOME}` to access the environment variable from Perl instead of using the one from shell. Note that depending on the quoting you might need to escape `$` then. *"And for some reason perl expands variables both within single and double quotes."* - Perl isn't expanding anything here but the shell does since you use double quotes around the perl statement, i.e. `eval "....shell will expand things here ..."`

Comment: Anytime you are using eval you are probably doing something wrong. You don't need to use eval to get environment variables into Perl. They are already there, in the `%ENV` hash. If you want to escape characters inside a regex, you can just use `\Q` to quote meta characters. If you add a simple test case, this would probably be an incredibly simple Perl task.

Comment: Re "*It seems like all forward slashes needs to be escaped.*", It's because you are building the following Perl program: `s//home/username\/_TV_rips//g`. That makesno sense. It should be `s/\/home\/username\/_TV_rips//g`. You shouldn't be trying to build Perl code from the shell. @Philippe's answer shows how to avoid doing that.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich that was very clear. With that info I could get the first the eval version to work with escaped dollar signs: `eval 'perl -pi -e "s/\$ENV{HOME}\/_TV_rips\///g"' '*$videoID.info.json'`. But I continued and removed eval after the other replies.

Comment: @TLP I was advised to use eval with perl somewhere else. I am happy to remove it. I got it working without eval.

Comment: `eval` takes a shell command and executes it. It only makes sense if you have `eval "$SHELL_CMD"`, including `eval "$( command_that_outputs_a_shell_cmd )"`

Answer (score 3):

You are building the following Perl program:

```perl
s//home/username\/_TV_rips\///g
```

That's quite wrong.

You shouldn't be attempting to build Perl code from the shell in the first place. There are a few ways you could pass values to the Perl code instead of generating Perl code. Since the value is conveniently in the environment, we can use

```sh
perl -i -pe's/\Q$ENV{HOME}\E\/_TV_rips\///' *"$videoID.info.json"
```

or better yet

```sh
perl -i -pe's{\Q$ENV{HOME}\E/_TV_rips/}{}' *"$videoID.info.json"
```

(Also note the lack of `eval` and the fixed quoting on the glob.)

Comment: Superb, thanks! The syntax in the second version is much cleaner. What tool do you recommend instead of perl for extended regex editing of file content?

Comment: @Kasam, 1) You didn't identify the reasons for ruling out `perl`, so there's no way to know what other tools are out of considerations  2) Tool recommendations are off-topic

Answer (score 1):

Just assembling the ideas in comments, this should achieve what you expected :

```
perl -pi -e 's{$ENV{HOME}/_TV_rips/}{}g' *$videoID.info.json
```

@ikegami thanks for your comment! It is indeed safer with \Q...\E, in case $HOME contains characters like $.

Comment: That didn't work on my system (perl 5, version 18). Using \Q as in @ikegami's reply did the trick.

Comment: @Kasam. You are mistaken. This works fine. The `\Q` is only supposed to help with special characters in `$ENV{HOME}`, of which there should never be any.  If you are relying on `\Q`, you are doing something wrong (like using `"...$HOME..."` instead of `'...$ENV{HOME}...'` and not using what we posted.

Comment: @ikegami I tried it again, it worked fine. Thanks  for the reminder. Even simpler syntax.

Answer (score 0):

All RegEx delimiters must of cource be escaped in input String.

But as Stefen stated, you can use other delimiters in perl, like `%, §`.

Special characters

1. `#` Perl comment - don't use this
2. `?,[], {}, $, ^, .` Regex control chars - must be escaped in Regex. That makes it easier if you have many slashes in your string.

You should always write a comment to make clear you are using different delimiters, because this makes your regex hard to read for inexperienced users.

Try out your RegEx here: https://regex101.com/r/cIWk1o/1